# Ordering columns and rows of cross-table by appearance in dataset

Tags: r, database, crosstab

Below, I have the following data that is ordered by the variable `mutation`. I am using `xtabs` to cross-tabulate the factor variable `ID` (rows) by the factor variable `subregion` (columns) based on the value of `attribute`. To reorder the factors by the order they appear in the dataset, I use `forcats::fct_reorder`. Based on the (truncated) output, this works with a very small dataset given below. However, my data has 966 unique `ID`s and ~58000 unique `subregions`. When I run similar code as below, it doesn't give the columns and rows in the right order.

Individuals appearing early in the dataset may be repeated later on because they have a mutation at a later location, but subregions do not appear later in the dataset because they are determined by their location. Additionally, for repeated `ID` and `subregion` (see `ID`s 4,5 and 21,22) will result in a cell with the *sum* of their `attribute` values.  Is there anyway to modify `xtabs` in order to retain the desired order? I'm also open to other cross-tabulation methods.

**Code**

```
library(forcats)

#Cross-tabulate ID by subregion using attribute
df_tab <- as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(df$attribute~fct_reorder(as.character(df$ID),df$mutation)+
                                   fct_reorder(as.character(df$subregion),df$mutation)))
```

**Truncated Output**

```
             OR4F5:E1:E1 SAMD11:E2:E2 NOC2L:E5:E5 NOC2L:E4:E4 KLHL17:E3:E3
TCGA-AN-A046      1.0085     0.000000    0.000000    0.000000      0.00000
TCGA-A2-A0CP      0.0000     1.003465    0.000000    0.000000      0.00000
TCGA-A8-A08H      0.0000     0.000000    1.436694    0.000000      0.00000
TCGA-GM-A2DM      0.0000     0.000000    0.000000    2.335915      0.00000
TCGA-D8-A1XM      0.0000     0.000000    0.000000    0.000000      2.17849
```

**Dataset**

```
"ID" "subregion" "mutation" "attribute"
"1" "TCGA-AN-A046" "OR4F5:E1:E1" 69767 1.00849961637455
"2" "TCGA-A2-A0CP" "SAMD11:E2:E2" 925952 1.00346517231111
"3" "TCGA-A8-A08H" "NOC2L:E5:E5" 956126 1.43669428919156
"4" "TCGA-GM-A2DM" "NOC2L:E4:E4" 956911 1.1679575001733
"5" "TCGA-GM-A2DM" "NOC2L:E4:E4" 956912 1.1679575001733
"6" "TCGA-D8-A1XM" "KLHL17:E3:E3" 961658 2.17848956802821
"7" "TCGA-BH-A18G" "KLHL17:E5:E5" 962441 48.0640560165975
"8" "TCGA-3C-AALI" "KLHL17:E8:E8" 963353 40.6525553849528
"9" "TCGA-AC-A62Y" "KLHL17:E9:E9" 964004 2.89875813313313
"10" "TCGA-AR-A2LE" "PLEKHN1:E1:E1" 966556 1.03540263019699
"11" "TCGA-E2-A14N" "PLEKHN1:E5:E5" 970728 21.8246585021196
"12" "TCGA-AO-A0J4" "PLEKHN1:E12:E12" 973506 1.24409284966302
"13" "TCGA-D8-A1J9" "HES4:E3:E3" 999551 1.24409284966302
"14" "TCGA-EW-A1PH" "ISG15:E2:E2" 1014276 72.4814235432147
"15" "TCGA-A2-A0T0" "AGRN:E2:E2" 1022338 21.8246585021196
"16" "TCGA-GM-A2DD" "AGRN:E3:E3" 1035303 1.06314569745364
"17" "TCGA-5L-AAT1" "AGRN:E4:E4" 1040690 1.24409284966302
"18" "TCGA-OL-A5RW" "AGRN:E8:E8" 1043314 2.20878819659627
"19" "TCGA-D8-A27M" "AGRN:E25:E25" 1049355 1.45844645372491
"20" "TCGA-AR-A1AI" "AGRN:E29:E29" 1050430 1.16479379564338
"21" "TCGA-5L-AAT0" "AGRN:E36:E36" 1055374 7.09932582548073
"22" "TCGA-5L-AAT0" "AGRN:E36:E36" 1055376 7.09932582548073
"23" "TCGA-C8-A8HP" "AGRN:E36:E36" 1055442 7.09932582548073
"24" "TCGA-A7-A4SD" "TTLL10:E13:E13" 1184971 1.24409284966302
"25" "TCGA-BH-A1F0" "SDF4:E4:E4" 1223283 1.46091816304331
"26" "TCGA-AO-A128" "SDF4:E4:E4" 1223330 1.46091816304331
"27" "TCGA-E9-A1R0" "SDF4:E2:E2" 1228592 3.86565576505924
"28" "TCGA-A2-A04P" "UBE2J2:E7:E7" 1255246 33.795587162655
"29" "TCGA-C8-A274" "UBE2J2:E7:E7" 1255342 33.795587162655
"30" "TCGA-5L-AAT1" "SCNN1D:E1:E1" 1281422 1.24409284966302
"31" "TCGA-AO-A128" "SCNN1D:E6:E6" 1287116 1.06314569745364
"32" "TCGA-E2-A15R" "SCNN1D:E7:E7" 1287596 2.89179279138711
"33" "TCGA-AC-A62V" "SCNN1D:E11:E11" 1290543 74.0747402078337
"34" "TCGA-BH-A18V" "ACAP3:E22:E22" 1294187 2.21398621447599
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen to duplicate `ID`+`subregion` rows, e.g. rows 4+5, and 21+22?

Comment: The cell value should be summed up for those.

Comment: You should include that in your main post, as this is a critical piece of information! Do you only want to sum `attribute` or also `mutation`?

Comment: I've included an update in my post below that addresses your revised problem statement; please take a look.

Comment: Just attribute. Mutation is just for ordering (at least with `fct_reorder`). I don't necessarily need `mutation` to create a cross-table.

Comment: Yes, I already got that:-) My solution below is based on `dplyr` and `tidyr` (no `fcr_reorder` and no `xtabs`).

Comment: Yes, that works great! It's also **much** faster than the solution with `xtabs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df.wide <- df %>%
    mutate(
        ID = factor(ID, levels = unique(.$ID[order(.$mutation)])),
        subregion = factor(subregion, levels = unique(.$subregion[order(.$mutation)]))) %>%
    group_by(ID, subregion) %>%
    mutate(n = 1:n()) %>%
    select(-mutation) %>%
    spread(subregion, attribute) %>%
    ungroup()
df.wide
## A tibble: 32 x 31
#   ID        n `OR4F5:E1:E1` `SAMD11:E2:E2` `NOC2L:E5:E5` `NOC2L:E4:E4`
#   <fct> <int>         <dbl>          <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
# 1 TCGA…     1          1.01          NA            NA            NA
# 2 TCGA…     1         NA              1.00         NA            NA
# 3 TCGA…     1         NA             NA             1.44         NA
# 4 TCGA…     1         NA             NA            NA             1.17
# 5 TCGA…     2         NA             NA            NA             1.17
# 6 TCGA…     1         NA             NA            NA            NA
# 7 TCGA…     1         NA             NA            NA            NA
# 8 TCGA…     1         NA             NA            NA            NA
# 9 TCGA…     1         NA             NA            NA            NA
#10 TCGA…     1         NA             NA            NA            NA
## … with 22 more rows, and 25 more variables: `KLHL17:E3:E3` <dbl>,
##   `KLHL17:E5:E5` <dbl>, `KLHL17:E8:E8` <dbl>, `KLHL17:E9:E9` <dbl>,
##   `PLEKHN1:E1:E1` <dbl>, `PLEKHN1:E5:E5` <dbl>, `PLEKHN1:E12:E12` <dbl>,
##   `HES4:E3:E3` <dbl>, `ISG15:E2:E2` <dbl>, `AGRN:E2:E2` <dbl>,
##   `AGRN:E3:E3` <dbl>, `AGRN:E4:E4` <dbl>, `AGRN:E8:E8` <dbl>,
##   `AGRN:E25:E25` <dbl>, `AGRN:E29:E29` <dbl>, `AGRN:E36:E36` <dbl>,
##   `TTLL10:E13:E13` <dbl>, `SDF4:E4:E4` <dbl>, `SDF4:E2:E2` <dbl>,
##   `UBE2J2:E7:E7` <dbl>, `SCNN1D:E1:E1` <dbl>, `SCNN1D:E6:E6` <dbl>,
##   `SCNN1D:E7:E7` <dbl>, `SCNN1D:E11:E11` <dbl>, `ACAP3:E22:E22` <dbl>
```

We explicitly order `factor` levels for `ID` and `subregion` by `mutation`, and add an `n` column that keeps track of duplicate `ID`+`subregion` rows. The rest is then a simple long to wide reshape.

---

### Update

Summing `attribute` values for duplicate `ID`+`subregion` values changes your problem statement slightly; in that case you can do

```
df.wide <- df %>%
    mutate(
        ID = factor(ID, levels = unique(.$ID[order(.$mutation)])),
        subregion = factor(subregion, levels = unique(.$subregion[order(.$mutation)]))) %>%
    group_by(ID, subregion) %>%
    summarise(attribute = sum(attribute)) %>%
    spread(subregion, attribute) %>%
    ungroup()
df.wide
## A tibble: 30 x 30
#   ID    `OR4F5:E1:E1` `SAMD11:E2:E2` `NOC2L:E5:E5` `NOC2L:E4:E4` `KLHL17:E3:E3`
#   <fct>         <dbl>          <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>          <dbl>
# 1 TCGA…          1.01          NA            NA            NA             NA
# 2 TCGA…         NA              1.00         NA            NA             NA
# 3 TCGA…         NA             NA             1.44         NA             NA
# 4 TCGA…         NA             NA            NA             2.34          NA
# 5 TCGA…         NA             NA            NA            NA              2.18
# 6 TCGA…         NA             NA            NA            NA             NA
# 7 TCGA…         NA             NA            NA            NA             NA
# 8 TCGA…         NA             NA            NA            NA             NA
# 9 TCGA…         NA             NA            NA            NA             NA
#10 TCGA…         NA             NA            NA            NA             NA
## … with 20 more rows, and 24 more variables: `KLHL17:E5:E5` <dbl>,
##   `KLHL17:E8:E8` <dbl>, `KLHL17:E9:E9` <dbl>, `PLEKHN1:E1:E1` <dbl>,
##   `PLEKHN1:E5:E5` <dbl>, `PLEKHN1:E12:E12` <dbl>, `HES4:E3:E3` <dbl>,
##   `ISG15:E2:E2` <dbl>, `AGRN:E2:E2` <dbl>, `AGRN:E3:E3` <dbl>,
##   `AGRN:E4:E4` <dbl>, `AGRN:E8:E8` <dbl>, `AGRN:E25:E25` <dbl>,
##   `AGRN:E29:E29` <dbl>, `AGRN:E36:E36` <dbl>, `TTLL10:E13:E13` <dbl>,
##   `SDF4:E4:E4` <dbl>, `SDF4:E2:E2` <dbl>, `UBE2J2:E7:E7` <dbl>,
##   `SCNN1D:E1:E1` <dbl>, `SCNN1D:E6:E6` <dbl>, `SCNN1D:E7:E7` <dbl>,
##   `SCNN1D:E11:E11` <dbl>, `ACAP3:E22:E22` <dbl>
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    '"ID" "subregion" "mutation" "attribute"
"1" "TCGA-AN-A046" "OR4F5:E1:E1" 69767 1.00849961637455
"2" "TCGA-A2-A0CP" "SAMD11:E2:E2" 925952 1.00346517231111
"3" "TCGA-A8-A08H" "NOC2L:E5:E5" 956126 1.43669428919156
"4" "TCGA-GM-A2DM" "NOC2L:E4:E4" 956911 1.1679575001733
"5" "TCGA-GM-A2DM" "NOC2L:E4:E4" 956912 1.1679575001733
"6" "TCGA-D8-A1XM" "KLHL17:E3:E3" 961658 2.17848956802821
"7" "TCGA-BH-A18G" "KLHL17:E5:E5" 962441 48.0640560165975
"8" "TCGA-3C-AALI" "KLHL17:E8:E8" 963353 40.6525553849528
"9" "TCGA-AC-A62Y" "KLHL17:E9:E9" 964004 2.89875813313313
"10" "TCGA-AR-A2LE" "PLEKHN1:E1:E1" 966556 1.03540263019699
"11" "TCGA-E2-A14N" "PLEKHN1:E5:E5" 970728 21.8246585021196
"12" "TCGA-AO-A0J4" "PLEKHN1:E12:E12" 973506 1.24409284966302
"13" "TCGA-D8-A1J9" "HES4:E3:E3" 999551 1.24409284966302
"14" "TCGA-EW-A1PH" "ISG15:E2:E2" 1014276 72.4814235432147
"15" "TCGA-A2-A0T0" "AGRN:E2:E2" 1022338 21.8246585021196
"16" "TCGA-GM-A2DD" "AGRN:E3:E3" 1035303 1.06314569745364
"17" "TCGA-5L-AAT1" "AGRN:E4:E4" 1040690 1.24409284966302
"18" "TCGA-OL-A5RW" "AGRN:E8:E8" 1043314 2.20878819659627
"19" "TCGA-D8-A27M" "AGRN:E25:E25" 1049355 1.45844645372491
"20" "TCGA-AR-A1AI" "AGRN:E29:E29" 1050430 1.16479379564338
"21" "TCGA-5L-AAT0" "AGRN:E36:E36" 1055374 7.09932582548073
"22" "TCGA-5L-AAT0" "AGRN:E36:E36" 1055376 7.09932582548073
"23" "TCGA-C8-A8HP" "AGRN:E36:E36" 1055442 7.09932582548073
"24" "TCGA-A7-A4SD" "TTLL10:E13:E13" 1184971 1.24409284966302
"25" "TCGA-BH-A1F0" "SDF4:E4:E4" 1223283 1.46091816304331
"26" "TCGA-AO-A128" "SDF4:E4:E4" 1223330 1.46091816304331
"27" "TCGA-E9-A1R0" "SDF4:E2:E2" 1228592 3.86565576505924
"28" "TCGA-A2-A04P" "UBE2J2:E7:E7" 1255246 33.795587162655
"29" "TCGA-C8-A274" "UBE2J2:E7:E7" 1255342 33.795587162655
"30" "TCGA-5L-AAT1" "SCNN1D:E1:E1" 1281422 1.24409284966302
"31" "TCGA-AO-A128" "SCNN1D:E6:E6" 1287116 1.06314569745364
"32" "TCGA-E2-A15R" "SCNN1D:E7:E7" 1287596 2.89179279138711
"33" "TCGA-AC-A62V" "SCNN1D:E11:E11" 1290543 74.0747402078337
"34" "TCGA-BH-A18V" "ACAP3:E22:E22" 1294187 2.21398621447599', header = T)
```